# Can't find images heroku django

Tags: django, heroku

I deployed the project on heroku, and everything seems to load, except for images, I do not understand what the problem is. There is an assumption that this is due to different folder names on the server and local machine, based on this screenshot:

[image]

Local storage -  static/img

Static settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

project structure:

[image]

Comment: Please show static settings

Comment: I added static settings

Comment: Can you try removing whitenoise, also remove it from apps.

Comment: Please also show your directory structure.

Comment: i deleted whitenoise now the website is without styles

Comment: Sorry, I thought that your static files were not being loaded too, I misread. Add whitenoise back. and can you rename `img/` to `images/`?

Comment: now img. Did you mean img to images?

Comment: yes and also replace from templates too

Comment: yeah, i thought about it and almost did it until you started help me. But but if i am used to calling the folder img somehow i can keep it

Comment: this solution didn't help